# Underlying Parsec Monad

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Many of the Parsec combinators I use are of a type such as:

```
foo :: CharParser st Foo
```

`CharParser` is defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Char.html#t:CharParser) as:

```
type CharParser st = GenParser Char st
```

`CharParser` is thus a type synonym involving `GenParser`, itself defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-String.html#t:GenParser) as:

```
type GenParser tok st = Parsec [tok] st
```

`GenParser` is then another type synonym, assigned using `Parsec`, defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Parsec) as:

```
type Parsec s u = ParsecT s u Identity
```

So `Parsec` is a partial application of `ParsecT`, itself listed [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:ParsecT) with type:

```
data ParsecT s u m a
```

along with the words:

> "ParsecT s u m a is a parser with stream type s, user state type u,
> underlying monad m and return type a."

What is the underlying monad? In particular, what is it when I use the `CharParser` parsers? I can't see where it's inserted in the stack. Is there a relationship to the use of the list monad in [Monadic Parsing in Haskell](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/pearl.pdf) to return multiple successful parses from an ambiguous parser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GenParser is defined in terms of Parsec, not ParsecT. Parsec in turn is defined as

```
type Parsec s u = ParsecT s u Identity
```

So the answer is that when using CharParser the underlying monad is the Identity monad.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to include that step. So it's the base of the monad transformer. I believe that has no relationship to the ambiguous parsing described in the Hutton/Meijer paper. So does that use of the list monad appear anywhere within the Parsec parser? Is Parsec only non-ambiguous? If so, is that encoded using `Maybe` or `Either`?

Comment: The underlying monad is not used by parsec itself, so it does not affect ambiguity.

Comment: I think what I was trying to ask about was the relationship between the list monad in the Hutton/Meijer paper; and the [Consumed](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Consumed) and [Reply](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Reply) types used in Parsec.

Answer (score 9):

In your case the underlying monad is `Identity`.  However ParsecT is different from most monad transformers in that it is an instance of the `Monad` class even if the type parameter `m` is not.  If you look at the source code you will note the lack of "`(Monad m) =>`" in the instance declaration.

So then you ask yourself, "If I were to have a non-trivial monad stack, where would it be used?"

There are a three of answers to that question:

1. It is used to `uncons` the next token out of the stream:

   ```
    class (Monad m) => Stream s m t | s -> t where
        uncons :: s -> m (Maybe (t,s))
   ```

   Notice that `uncons` takes an `s` (the stream of tokens `t`) and returns its result wrapped in your monad.  This allows one to do interesting thing while or even during the process of getting the next token.
2. It is used in the resulting output of each parser.  This means you can create parsers that don't touch the input but take action in the underlying monad and use the combinators to bind them to regular parsers.  In other words, `lift (x :: m a) :: ParsecT s u m a`.
3. Finally, the end result of RunParsecT and friends (until you build up to the point where `m` is replaced by `Identity`) return their results wrapped in this monad.

There is not a relationship between this monad and the one from [Monadic Parsing in Haskell](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/pearl.pdf). In this case Hutton and Meijer are referring to the monad instance for ParsecT itself. The fact that in Parsec-3.0.0 and beyond ParsecT has become a monad transformer with an underlying monad is not relevant to the paper.

What I think you are looking for however is where the list of possible results went.  In Hutton and Meijer the parser returns a list of all possible results while Parsec stubbornly returns only one. I think you are looking at the `m` in the result and thinking to yourself that the list of results must be hiding in there somewhere.  It is not.

Parsec, for reasons of efficiency, made a choice to prefer the first matching result in Hutton and Meijer's list of results. This let's it toss away both the unused results in the tail of Hutton and Meijer's list and also the front of the stream of tokens because we never backtrack.  In parsec, given the combined parser `a <|> b`, if `a` consumes any input `b` will never be evaluated.  The way around this is `try` which will reset the state back to where it was if `a` fails then evaluate `b`.

You asked in the comments if this was done using `Maybe` or `Either`.  The answer is "almost but not quite." If you look at the low lever `run*` functions you see that they return an Algebraic type which tell weather input was consumed then a second which give either the result or an error message.  These types work kind of like `Either`, but even they are not used directly.  Rather then stretch this out further, I'll refer you to [the post](http://panicsonic.blogspot.com/2009/12/adventures-in-parsec.html) by Antoine Latter  that explains how this works and why it is done this way.